# Do Pharaoh ants eat sealant?

Tags: ant

My high-rise apartment has had pharaoh ants for the past 3 years (maybe more).  It is being handled by a pest control company.  I am not looking for countermeasures.

One of the countermeasures advised by the pest control technician is to seal the opening through which my water pipes travel.  The apartment management sprayed a sealant that looks like whipped cream, but had a distinct chemical smell (images below).

The ant sightings are usually on the kitchen counter top, mostly around the perimeter of the sink.  I try to wipe the counter often, and keep the area dry.  The sightings were getting kind of low just before the hole was sealed, sometimes going for days without a sighting.  Since that day, however, the sightings have been on the upswing.  Quite a coincidence.

I wondered whether the pharaoh ants are attracted to the chemical sealant as a source of food.  Googling doesn't turn anything up for pharaoh-ant-eat-sealant.  Does anyone know about the plausibility of this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's possible,. The sealant is an expanding polyurethane foam, marketed in the US as "Great Stuff", among other brands from a number of different companies. Basically, it's plastic. Ants or other pests could chew through it by removing small pieces, but I doubt they're eating it, as it has no nutritional value.

Comment: If it has no nutritional value, then it seems that the plastic foam isn't attracting the ants.  There must be another explanation for their sudden increase, coincidentally starting on the day that the foam was applied.

Comment: Just a thought, but - instead of sealing them out - might you have sealed them *in*?

Comment: It might be possible that at the same time the pest control company sprayed something in the basement and other parts of the building that forced out the ants.

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket: I've been told over the years that the number of an sightings in my unit is way too low for me to be hosting the colony.  So if I trapped a few scouts in my apartment (which I likely did), then why would the number of sightings steadily increase since the day the opening was sealed?

Comment: @FluidCode: It was the apartment building staff who sealed the the opening, not the pest control company.  Of course, that just leaves fewer avenues into my unit, not zero avenues.  It is possible something elsewhere caused more ants to be closer to my unit, and more ants to enter.  The timing of the increase is quite a coincidence, so I think it is not likely, but still possible.

Comment: @user2153235 Why don't you leave for few days some flypaper in some strategic points. In this way you could find out where they come from.

Comment: @FluidCode: Huh.  Never thought of that.  It's like troublehooting a technical problem.  Thanks, I'll have to mull on some locations at which to start.

Comment: It doesn't need to have nutritional value, if there's something on the other side that's attracting them. Have you looked at the foam to see if anything has been chewing on it or penetrated it? This could also be a good location to leave some of your flypaper.

Comment: It's hard to get up and close to inspect, and my vision isn't that good.  But the photo's show underside of the sink.  There's nothing there.  The outside is whatever is on the other side of the wall with the hole that was sealed.  The contents of the inside and outside did not change when opening was sealed, so that doesn't explain the presence of more ants.  I should clarify that the greater sightings are on the counter top, around the perimeter of the sink.  I try to wipe down often, and that hasn't changed.

Comment: @MattDMo: Would you care to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @user2153235 sure. What country are you in, so I can localize my answer?

Comment: @MattDMo: Canada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sealant in question is a self-curing expanding urethane foam, marketed under numerous brands and formulations in the US and Canada such as DuPont Great Stuff, Loctite Tite Foam, and DAP Touch 'n Foam. It is widely available at hardware stores and home centers.

After curing it forms a hard cross-linked polyurethane mass - essentially a plastic foam. While it has no nutritional value and is solid enough to be marketed in a [pest control application](https://www.touch-n-foam.ca/mouseshield.html), it could theoretically be chewed through by a determined-enough ant colony, as the marketing material for that particular product doesn't say anything about insect repellant properties, only mice. Non-rodent-repellant formulations are known to be susceptible to eventual "chew-through" and inhabitation by both mice/rats and insects such as [carpenter ants](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/forum/spray-foam-insulation-and-carpenter-ants). Great Stuff markets a [Pest Block formulation](https://www.greatstuff.dupont.com/products/greatstuff-pestblock.html) that supposedly is formulated to prevent chewing, but its claims regarding insects are a little vague. You'd have to ask your building management if they used a pest-blocking foam.

You say that the sightings started to swing up again a day after the sealant was applied. I would imagine that it would take some weeks for a colony to chew through the amount of foam pictured (even longer if an insect-repelling product was used), and they would need a rather compelling reason to keep at it, as the foam itself is not a food for them. It's likely that you're seeing ants that were already in your apartment when the "escape routes" were sealed, and they're simply foraging in a more visible manner now because they don't have other sources of food. On the other hand, the fact that you think you're seeing more ants now after the pipe openings were sealed could simply be a coincidence. Remember, correlation does not mean causation.

Comment: Thank you! Some time after I posted my original question, I added details, such as the fact that the sightings increased on the very day that the sealant was applied. Wiping with bleach seems to bring down sightings again. I hope that this surge is temporary due to trapped scouting ants, because I dislike the residue of bleach on the kitchen counter. The vapours aren't healthy, either. On a related note, there is no change in the food source on my side of the wall, and since the other side is just pipe space, I don't expect whatever passes as food on that side has changed either.

Comment: @user2153235 sorry, I didn't read the edited question closely enough regarding the timeline. I changed my wording a bit. Based on that, I'm pretty sure that you're seeing trapped scouts, not new ants.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a very encouraging outlook!

Comment: It has been a week since the sealant was applied, and the number of ant sightings seem to be staying at their heightened levels.  Sigh........

Comment: @user2153235 Interesting. Do you have ant traps in your apartment? Depending on their kind, they should be having some sort of effect by now, assuming my theory is correct...

Comment: The professional pest control company has laid down bait of various types and in various forms (directly dropping goop on various places versus the less messy plastic containers of bait).  The "stuff" has varied through the years.  At the beginning, I also got my own.  Each new chemical brought about a temporary lull.  The ants seem to be adapting before they are wiped out (a problem with Pharaoh ants, whose colonies can easily split). Completely wiping them out is hard in a high-rise, especially with the warming weather.

Comment: My bleach solution seems ill-advised, both because of the fumes and the [adverse effects](https://favoredstoneguides.com/can-you-use-bleach-on-laminate-countertops) on laminate countertops.  It looks as if I will have to get comfortable again with ants on my food preparation surface.